# Finding anchor HTML elements without href attributes using regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to search through my project for `<a>` elements that are missing their `href` attribute, using a regular expression to match the results I'm looking for.

I first tried the following expression: `/<a (?!href).*?>/` This works for a lot of elements but fails as soon as the href isn't the first attribute. I then tried `<a .*?(?!href).*?>` but this too failed as the `.*?` expression was too greedy despite adding the `?` to make sure the `*` was lazy.

What am I missing? The test set I'm using is as follows:

```
<a href=""></a>
<a href=""" data-toggle="tab" ></a>
<a data-toggle="tab" href="foobar"></a>
<a data-toggle="tab" type=""asdf>test</a>
<a test="test"></a>
```

Only the last two hyperlinks should match my search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be aware that your answer doesn't match:

- `<a alt="href"></a>`
- `<a style"newhref"></a>`
  for example.

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/xY81Lb/1/)

I'd use [Tempered Greedy Pattern](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

`<a(?:(?!\bhref=)[^>])*>`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/xY81Lb/2)

Comment: Thanks for providing these two testcases, completely forgot about that possibility. I fixed this by using `<a (?!.*?href=).*?>`, which seems to work right. According to regex101 you solution takes almost 500 steps though, vs the ~260 steps my formula takes. (not that I care for performance in this simple text search) I'll read up on the pattern you linked.

Comment: @MMM: Sure, this regex is less efficient but more accurate ;) Yours doesn't match (very improbable) edge cases like `<a alt="href=">`. This is just to inform future readers.

Comment: That's a good point you make, didn't think of that terrible but possible value either. Thank you for your input!

Comment: @MMM: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I figured out what I was doing wrong while typing up my question.

The reason `.*?` didn't work was because it kept matching endlessly before the negative lookahead. By moving `.*?` into the negative lookahead I managed to make it work:

```
<a (?!.*?href=).*?>
```

Including the zero-or-more quantifier in the negative lookahead makes it part of the text I *don't* want to match, without having it match text before the negative lookahead can get to it. Thanks to Toto for reminding me to add a `=` so I don't ignore attribute values containing "href"!